How to publish and download artifacts as zip in azure yaml pipeline
I converted the classic pipeline into onebranch yaml pipeline. All tasks are completed but unable to see the zip files inside of the artifacts folder. I have added the yaml code for build and publish the web as follows,
                 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
                 displayName: Publish Web Solution
                 inputs:
                   command: publish
                   publishWebProjects: false
                   projects: >-
                      {solutionpath}

                   arguments: >-
                      --configuration Release --output
                      '$(REPOROOT)\obartifacts'
                   zipAfterPublish: true
                   modifyOutputPath: false

But i am not able to see the artifacts as zip folder. If anything i am missing please let me know. But i am getting an error as follows,
The imported project "C:\__t\dotnet\sdk\6.0.427\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\__t\dotnet\sdk\6.0.427\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

               


You did not add the PublishPipelineArtifact@1 task to publish the generated ZIP file.

You did not add the PublishPipelineArtifact@1 task to publish the generated ZIP file form the output directory.
You can set your pipeline like as below:
#azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: 'Build'
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Web solution'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: 'path/to/solution.sln'
      arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration)'
  
  # Output the generate ZIP file into the directory "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/obartifacts".
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Web solution'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: 'path/to/solution.sln'
      arguments: '--no-build -c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/obartifacts'
      modifyOutputPath: false

  # Publish the ZIP file from the directory "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)".
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: drop

The result.

Then in the subsequent jobs or pipelines, you can use the DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 task to download the published ZIP file from the build job/pipeline.


But onebranch will not take this task as by default it will take

@Duk, The PublishPipelineArtifact@1 task will not be automatically added and run in any jobs by default, you must explicitly add it in your job when you want to publish some files as the pipeline artifacts to be used by the subsequent jobs or pipelines.

@Duk, By default, the DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 will be automatically run in the deploy jobs of YAML pipelines and each job of classic release pipelines, if there are available artifact sources.
